# Abstracting Java Robot Function

Tags: java, keyevent, awtrobot

I'm having a little bit of a play around with the Java Robot function.

However as i think it's a major pain in the backside i was wondering if i could abstract the function and create a faster way.

Now Firstly i have done the following:

```
public abstract class Cyborg {

    public static void Cyborg(KeyEvent args[]) throws AWTException{
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot(); 
            for(KeyEvent k:args){
                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.k); 
            }
        } catch(AWTException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which i am currently a little baffled with i am currently getting an error that k cannot be resolved. However in the `KeyEvent args[]` section should this be classed as a KeyEvent or should this just be a string? As i am from a PHP background i am starting to get to grips with java. Can anyone advise if this is the best way to go about this? And also as to why `KeyEvent.k` won't resolve whether it is a `KeyEvent` or if it is a `String`? Any other advise on if this will work/won't work or issues to try and avoid would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.k);
```

This won't work, because this will attempt to find a `static` `member` of the class `KeyEvent` called `k`. You've named your incremental object `k`, so use `k`.

```
robot.keyPress(k.getKeyCode());
```

**More thorough Explanation**

When you say the following:

```
 String[] strs = {"hello", "there", "my", "friend"};

 for(String str : strs)
 {
     // Do something.
 }
```

What you're making the computer do has the same effect as:

```
 for(int x = 0; x < strs.length; x++)
 {
     String str = strs[x];
 }
```

So you're defining a `String` object named `str` that will contain the current `String` object that is contained within the `strs` array.

Comment: Yes i have but setting it to k is an integer variation of the Key not the actual Key Value

Comment: No, `k` is a `KeyEvent` object. - Apologies. Edited to make it more clear.

Comment: It states "the method keyPress in the type robot is not applicable for the arguments (KeyEvent)"

Comment: Your right that has done the trick. Now is there any information that you can think of that would stop this from working? Other then the fact the argument needs to be one character at a time so char[] would be better suited right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Are there any scenarios that could cause this to fail? Sure, but that's why you have a `try-catch`.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure i'm new into the world of java but you have answered the question so i will mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.k);
```

Should be like this

```
robot.keyPress(k.getKeyCode());
```

Comment: Yes i have but setting it to k is an integer variation of the Key not the actual Key Value